# Assembler memory access error

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I have a problem with Assembler 64 bit I simply tyring to use the div -> 7/2 but I get an memory acces error not sure why

```
 section .text

        global _start:
_start:
    xor     rdx,    rdx
    mov     rax,    7
    mov     rbx,    2
    div     rbx,
    mov     rax,    rdx
    ret
```

I am using the 64 bit registers so there are no problems with the registers so everything should work fine but I get an error don't know why

**Edit**

I know thats not a problem with assembler but I did something wrong but not sure what

I am using nasm

**Update Code**

```
  section .text

    global _start:
_start:
    xor     rdx,    rdx
    mov     rax,    7
    mov     rbx,    2
    div     rbx,
    int 80h
    mov     rax,    1
```

now it does nothing without any error

Comment: Please show us the code where you are calling this function.

Comment: The problem is the `ret` at the end - if you run this without libc on linux, you can't use `ret` to end the process, you must use the exit syscall.

Comment: @Ruud I Don't understand what you mean but I have a a file called divtest.asm with in the terminal I enter nasm -f elf64 divtest.asm and then ld -s -o modtest modtest.o so and then  ./modtest between this commands there are no errors only after the last command I get  the memmory access error without any line where the problem is

Comment: @Jester I add int 80 instead of ret but I still get the same error

Comment: Please use a good 'hello world' example to learn from, e.g.: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmexamples/

Comment: In 64 bit mode you should use the `syscall` instruction, and it makes more sense to set up the arguments beforehand ;) Also the exit syscall has number 60. So, what you need is:  `mov eax, 60; syscall`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ret` if you use `GCC` as linker. You have to name the entry-label `main`. Don't forget to populate `EAX` with the exitcode.

**test.asm:**

```
extern: printf

section .data
    fmt: db `result: %lu  remainder: %lu\n`

section .text

    global main:
main:
    xor     rdx,    rdx
    mov     rax,    7
    mov     rbx,    2
    div     rbx

    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, rax
    ; mov rdx, rdx
    xor eax, eax
    call printf

    mov eax, 0
    ret
```

**Build & run:**

```
nasm -felf64 test.asm
gcc -otest -m64 test.o
./test
```

---

If you use `LD` as linker you have to manage the exit by yourself. Replace the `ret` block by:

```
mov ebx,0           ; exit code, 0=normal
mov eax,1           ; exit command
int 0x80            ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel
```

or (recommended for x86-64):

```
mov   rax, 60       ; sys_exit
mov   rdi, 0        ; return 0 (success)
syscall             ; syscall
```

**Build & run:**

```
nasm -felf64 test.asm
ld -e main -m elf_x86_64 -I/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc -o test test.o
./test
```